# Calling a server side method in a view on a anchor tag onclick

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onclick, client-server

I am new to MVC. I have a view with a few anchor tags which I want to add an onclick too. I need this onclick event to trigger a method call in the model. I would like to do this without any ajax.

I have tried `<a onclick="<%Model.Method%>">` but this triggers the method on load while I need it triggered onclick.

Comment: The `<a href="@Model.Method">link</a>` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the method from java script without using the Ajax then you can achieve that with the following code:

**View Code:**

```
<a onclick="testfunc()">clickme</a>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testfunc() {

        var url = "../Home/About";   //Here it is controllername/ActionName
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

I Hope this is what you want , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedback

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue and i was able to resolve by putting the IActionResult method (Delete) and the directory inside a double parenthesis like this
<a onClick="Delete('/Admin/Product/Delete${data}')" /a>

hope this work for you

Comment: To improve this answer you could show an example snippet of code along with details of why this worked for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is just using JavaScript to redirect the user to another URL or controller/action.

A better, and more MVC-like solution would be to simply use the MVC provided UrlHelper in the view to create a route to the required action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">clickme</a>
```

This would result in a regular link that sends the user to `/Home/About` and requires no JavaScript at all.

The signature for the `Url.Action` method is:

```cs
public virtual string Action (string actionName, string controllerName);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string) for other overloads and documentation.